# Mi metodo se inicia en el segundo click al boton en C#

Tags: c#

Lo que tengo es un boton de buscar, que se conecta a la base de datos, pero entonces cuando le doy a buscar y el TextBox txtEstado no esta vacio, este debe inhabilitar los otros txtbox, pero esto lo hace cuando hago la consulta con otra busqueda, es decir en el segundo click, pero necesito que cuando el txtbox este con valores estos se inhabiliten de una vez, al precionar el boton buscar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //metodo buscar
        BuscaRegistro(txtCodCli.Text);


        }
        private void FBorrado()
        {

        if ( txtEstado.Text != String.Empty)
        {
        txtNomCli.Enabled = false;
        txtApeCli.Enabled = false;
        txtDirCli.Enabled = false;


        }
        else
        {
                txtNomCli.Enabled = true;
                txtApeCli.Enabled = true;
                txtDirCli.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
 private bool BuscaRegistro(string codigo)
        {
           
            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conexion);
           
            try
            {
                String CadenaSql = "select nomcli, apecli, dircli, estado from sftclie0 where codcli=" + codigo;

                MySqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(CadenaSql, cn);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                cn.Open();
                Adaptador.Fill(ds);
                cn.Close();

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    txtNomCli.Text = "";
                    txtApeCli.Text = "";
                    txtDirCli.Text = "";
                    txtEstado.Text = "";
                    txtNomCli.Focus();
                    Encontrado = 0;
                    return false;

                }
                else
                {
                    txtNomCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nomcli"].ToString();
                    txtApeCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["apecli"].ToString();
                    txtDirCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dircli"].ToString();
                    txtEstado.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Estado"].ToString();
                    txtNomCli.Focus();
                    Encontrado = 1;
                    return true;
                }


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No pudo conectar a la base de datos");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Hay alguna manera en que el metodo Fborrado se incie en el primer click, es decir que si estado tiene valor este se deshabilite, pero en la primera consulta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando llamas a FBorrado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no veo en que parte del código mandas llamar a la función FBorrado(), segun lo que entendi, deberias de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //metodo buscar
        BuscaRegistro(txtCodCli.Text);
        FBorrado();//Llamar a la funcion

        }
        private void FBorrado()
        {

        if ( txtEstado.Text != String.Empty)
        {
        txtNomCli.Enabled = false;
        txtApeCli.Enabled = false;
        txtDirCli.Enabled = false;


        }
        else
        {
                txtNomCli.Enabled = true;
                txtApeCli.Enabled = true;
                txtDirCli.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
 private bool BuscaRegistro(string codigo)
        {
           
            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conexion);
           
            try
            {
                String CadenaSql = "select nomcli, apecli, dircli, estado from sftclie0 where codcli=" + codigo;

                MySqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(CadenaSql, cn);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                cn.Open();
                Adaptador.Fill(ds);
                cn.Close();

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    txtNomCli.Text = "";
                    txtApeCli.Text = "";
                    txtDirCli.Text = "";
                    txtEstado.Text = "";
                    txtNomCli.Focus();
                    Encontrado = 0;
                    return false;

                }
                else
                {
                    txtNomCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nomcli"].ToString();
                    txtApeCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["apecli"].ToString();
                    txtDirCli.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dircli"].ToString();
                    txtEstado.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Estado"].ToString();
                    txtNomCli.Focus();
                    Encontrado = 1;
                    return true;
                }


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No pudo conectar a la base de datos");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!! te recomiendo mirar [answer]... las respuestas deben estar explicadas. Entiendo que en este caso es dificil explicar algo que ni siquiera esta claro en la pregunta.. en ese caso, siempre esperamos que se aclare el problema...

Answer (score 0):

que te parece mejor hacerlo con el evento de TextChanged del textBox, este evento se activara cada que el texto del textbox cambie de valor

```
private void EstadoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(EstadoTextBox.Text))
    {
       //Codigo para deshabilitar los otros textBox
    }else
    {
       //Codigo para habilitar los otros TextBox
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva :)